# Performance benefits of Apache Tomcat native connectors

Tags: performance, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, native

I have compiled and deployed the native connectors for Tomcat and have run my load testing benchmarks. There is no measurable difference.

So my question is, under which circumstances are native connectors demonstratably faster? and can they be tuned to gain more performance from them.

I do not mean "how do I benchmark to show an increase", but rather what circumstances recommend the use of the connectors. As of yet I cannot see a difference for my application, so I wonder what the benefits of these connectors are.

Comment: Hunting for a benchmark to prove (or disprove) an optimisation is back-to-front, no? You write a benchmark according to your performance requirements, and then optimize accordingly.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I wonder under what circumstances will I see a performance increase and so what circumstances should I bother using this native connector?

Comment: Do you use SSL ?  The native connectors provide great speedups for https.

Comment: At this time I don't but I may in the future. Thanks

Comment: A google for "tomcat apr benchmarks" returns a number of useful-looking results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems I've found my answer through Google:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Tomcat-Benchmark-Procedure/

It seems as though the default connector is faster as I am not using SSL. My own performance tests have confirmed this for my application.

Comment: link is broken and this is why links should not be answers :-/